# How to insert array in MongoDB? Node Js

Tags: node.js, arrays, mongodb, mongoose

I'm working on Node js server and use the mongoDB with driver mongoose. So, how can I insert an array in database. Here is my Schema:

```
    const SubjectsSchema = new Schema(
  {
    id: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    subjects: [
      {
        id: { type: Number, required: true },
        subject: { type: String, required: true },
      },
    ],
  },
  { versionKey: false }
);
```

And here how I add new element:

```
let subjects = new Subjects({
      id: req.params.class,
      subjects: { id: 0, subject: "Maths"},
    subjects: {id: 1, subject: "IT"},
    subjects: {id: 2, subject: "Physics"},
    });
subjects.save();
```

But in db created only last element. So how can create a correct array?

Comment: Here you have the answer on your question: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#arrays

Answer (score 0):

You are supposed to pass it as an array, like your model definition

```js
let subjects = new Subjects({
      id: req.params.class,
      subjects: [{ id: 0, subject: "Maths"}, 
                {id: 1, subject: "IT"}, 
                {id: 2, subject: "Physics"}
                ]
    });
subjects.save();
```